# What is SQL equivalent for STRING_AGG in Oracle for the below SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, hana

The below SQL code works perfectly well in SAP HANA.

The issue is when I am trying to migrate the database from SAP HANA to Oracle SQL, `STRING_AGG` function will not work. In Oracle `LISTAGG` function is used instead of `STRING_AGG`. `LISTAGG` is not working for me in SAP HANA. I want to adjust the part of the SQL code containing `STRING_AGG` with its alternate equivalent such that it satisfies both SAP HANA and Oracle.

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW VIEW_RADTEST_CLICK_TODAY AS
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_num,
        v1.*
FROM 
(
SELECT  v.consult_date,
        v.PATIENT_EMPLOYEE_ID,
        v.PATIENT_KWT_NKWT,
        v.PATIENT_NAME,
        v.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        v.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
        v.DOCTORS_ID,
        v.DOCTOR_NAME,
        v.OFFICE_ID,
        v.OFFICE_NAME,
        count(cl.LABTEST_ID) AS "PATIENT_RADTEST_COUNT",
        STRING_AGG(CASE 
                        WHEN v.OFFICE_ID in(4,5,6,7,8)  THEN cl.LABTEST_ID 
                        ELSE 0
                    END,',') AS "LABTEST_ID",
        STRING_AGG(CASE 
                        WHEN v.OFFICE_ID in(4,5,6,7,8)  THEN ts.TEST_NAME 
                        ELSE 0
                    END,',') AS "TEST_NAME",
        STRING_AGG(CASE 
                        WHEN v.OFFICE_ID in(4,5,6,7,8)  THEN ts.CATEGORY_ID 
                        ELSE 0
                    END,',') AS "CATEGORY_ID",
        STRING_AGG(CASE 
                        WHEN v.OFFICE_ID in(4,5,6,7,8)  THEN tc.CATEGORY_NAME 
                        ELSE 0
                    END,',') AS "CATEGORY_NAME"
FROM ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_DOCTOR_CONSULT_TODAY v
INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.CONSULT_LABTEST cl
    on(v.CONSULT_ID=cl.CONSULT_ID)
INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.TEST_SETUP ts
    on(cl.LABTEST_ID=ts.TEST_ID)
INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.TEST_CATEGORY tc
     ON (ts.CATEGORY_ID=tc.CATEGORY_ID)
WHERE v.CONSULT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE
AND ts.ACTIVE_STATUS ='Y'
AND tc.ACTIVE_STATUS ='Y'
AND ts.LAB_TYPE IN('X','O')
GROUP BY 
        v.consult_date,
        v.PATIENT_EMPLOYEE_ID,
        v.PATIENT_KWT_NKWT,
        v.PATIENT_NAME,
        v.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        v.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
        v.DOCTORS_ID,
        v.DOCTOR_NAME,
        v.OFFICE_ID,
        v.OFFICE_NAME
ORDER BY v.OFFICE_NAME 
)AS v1;
```

Comment: "LISTAGG is not working for me in SAP HANA." is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us: why you think it is not working; the behaviour it is producing (is it raising an error, is it working but not giving the output you expect, etc.); or what you expect the result to be. Please [edit] your question and provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data; details of the issues/errors with your code; the output of your code; and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SAP HANA, but - just to *warn* you - maybe you won't be that lucky as you hoped you would. Database vendors have *similar* functions which return the same result, but not all of them (the functions) are standard. That's what you learnt on `STRING_AGG` and `LISTAGG`.

Another option might be `XMLAGG`; here's an example:

```
SQL> SELECT RTRIM (
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, e.ename || ', ') ORDER BY e.ename).EXTRACT (
  3               '//text()'),
  4            ', ') AS result
  5    FROM emp e
  6   WHERE e.deptno = 10;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK, KING, MILLER
```

As I said: I don't know SAP HANA so this is just another option which works in Oracle. See if it helps.

---

(Just to mention it: Oracle versions lower than 12c contained undocumented function named `WM_CONCAT`. I presume SAP HANA doesn't know it, but - even if it did - skip that option. Function doesn't even exist in 12c and higher versions.)

---

Finally: user-defined function. If nothing else helps, try to write your own function which *simulates* what built-in ones do, but which would contain code that compiles in both SAP HANA and Oracle. I'd expect it to behave *worse* than built-in functions, though.